# When to use semicolons in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I know that semicolons are used as terminators in REPL. But I'm confused about when to use them in a source file.

For example it is not necessary after `val x = 1`. But if I omit it after `use "foo.sml"`, the compiler will complain about it.

Then, what are the rules on using semicolons?

Answer (score 14):

Semicolons are used for a number of syntactic entities in SML.  They are normally used to create sequences of, e.g., expressions or declarations.  Here's a link to the SML grammar:

http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html

In your case, you are interested in the semicolon for declarations (the *dec* class).  Note that the semicolon that creates a sequence of decs is optional.  You never actually need it when writing SML modules, and it is rare to see them.  For example

```
structure S = struct
  val x = 5
  fun f x = x
  val z = x + x
end
```

not

```
structure S = struct
  val x = 5;
  fun f x = x;
  val z = x + x
end
```

In a source file, the only place you normally use a semicolon is separating expressions that have side-effects.  For example,

```
val x = ref 5
val _ = (x := !x + 1; x := !x+ 2)
```

but this usage is rare.

The smlnj repl only evaluates declarations when it sees a semicolon though, so you should use a semicolon whenever you want to see or play with the value.  I think the `use "foo.sml";` case is confusing because it's not a declaration; it's an expression.  I imagine that the repl converts expressions like `use "foo.sml"` into `val _ = use "foo.sml"`.   Thus it needs the semicolon to tell the repl to really run it, as above.  As a side note, there is nothing special about `use`.  It is simply a function of type `string -> unit`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know why it isn't necessary in declarations. And then could you please explain why it is needed in `use "foo.sml";`? I still don't understant it.

Comment: Thanks for you clarification. Does it mean that in a source file (not REPL), if I write an expression in a single line, like `1+1`, I have to terminate it with an semicolon?

Comment: Yes, unless you want the expression to continue to the next line, e.g. `1\n +\n 1;`  As a rule of thumb, use semicolon in the repl when you want to see the result.