# use syntax results in syntax error: replacing VAL with EQUALOP

Tags: sml, ml

I am implementing a function that takes two dates that are of type `(int * int * int)`: the first part is the year, the second part is the month and the third part is the day. It should return `true` if the first date is older than the second.

I want to test the function and I'm having problems with that. This is the file `ex1.sml`

```
fun is_older(d1 : (int * int * int), d2 : (int * int * int)) =
    if #1 d1 < #2 d2 then
        true
    else if #2 d1 < #2 d2 then
        true
    else
        #3 d1 < #3 d2
```

And this is the file `ex1-test.sml` that should test the function:

```
use "ex1.sml"

val test1 = is_older ((1,2,3),(2,3,4)) = true
```

Whenever I try to run this last file, by loading in the REPL, I always end up with the error: `Error: syntax error: replacing  VAL with  EQUALOP`

However if I put the test in `ex1.ml` and load it in the REPL it doesn't give any error.

```
fun is_older(d1 : (int * int * int), d2 : (int * int * int)) =
    if #1 d1 < #2 d2 then
        true
    else if #2 d1 < #2 d2 then
        true
    else
        #3 d1 < #3 d2

val test1 = is_older ((1,2,3),(2,3,4)) = true
```

I would like to have the tests in a separate file which then includes the definitions and runs the tests, as I was trying to do above. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat oddly, this is one of the rare cases where semicolons are required in SML even outside the REPL. If you change your test file to:

```
use "ex1.sml";

val test1 = is_older ((1,2,3),(2,3,4)) = true
```

then it will work as expected. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19237803/4996248) for more about semicolons in SML.

Answer (score 1):

Since John found the bug, here is some code feedback:

1. This is probably a case where records with named fields are better suited:

   ```
   type date = {year : int, month : int, day : int}
   ```

   This way you don't mix up the order of the otherwise interchangeable `int`s.

   Date formats are notoriously diverse. People might think it's y-m-d, m-d-y or d-m-y.
2. Your function seems to have another bug:

   ```
   val test_this = is_older ((2000, 1, 1), (1999, 2, 2))
   ```

   But 2000 isn't older than 1999.
3. Using *if-then-else* when the result is a boolean is slightly redundant:

   ```
   fun is_older (date1 : date, date2 : date) =
       #year date1  < #year date2 orelse
       #month date1 < #month date2 orelse
       #day date1   < #day date2
   ```

   (preserving the bug from 2.)

Comment: Yes there was a bug with the code and you're right that the code is redundant as it is. Thanks for the heads up.